# SurfaceView on screen at all times

Tags: android, surfaceview

Is it possible in Android to create a SurfaceView that always shows on top regardless what app  or activity is being displayed?

Answer (score 0):

it's not about a surfaceview,it's about window type.
the window you want to create is system-type window.